# Custom Maintenance Page

Tags: maintenance

I'd like to create a custom Maintenance Page for my needs, but not only when wordpress is updating. I just want to close my site for a period with all the necessarily status code sent.  What is the best way to do it?

Comment: There are many such maintenance plugins available. If you really looking for a custom page, there are many tutorials out there. All you need to do is a simple google search. If this doesn't fit your needs, please [edit] your question and add all relevant code and info and **explain why** it is not working for you

Comment: The problem is all of the existing plugins doesn't work. No idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such maintenance mode, I found the following plugin a better one (with currently rated a 4.1 on 5):

> [**Easy Maintenance Mode**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-maintenance-mode-coming-soon/) — WordPress Plugins

It's a good one, and the screenshots are there to describe its look and functionality. It'll create a maintenance banner foo all other users except the Admin. It's has a good user connectivity with the social networking links below, so the user who are seeing the Maintenance notice, won't go away - they will be in touch with your social updates.

And there are many facilities described in the plugin page.

BTW, if you find difficulties functioning any plugin like this, try switching to the default theme (Generally TwentyFourteen), and try deactivating all other plugins and activate them one by one to find which one is conflicting. It may help to debug the plugin's conflict.

Comment: That plugin works perfectly fine with no conflicts! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user48915: if an answer perfectly fits your need, just click on the checkmark to accept the answer. It'd be helpful for future users too. But it's not mandatory. :)